# PHP - count unique inner array instances in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have the following array, and would like to count all instances of the inner array.

```
Array ( 
     [0] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d) 
     [1] => Array ( [0] => c [1] => a) 
     [2] => Array ( [0] => b [1] => d)
     [3] => Array ( [0] => a [1] => d)
     )
```

I am looking at a count so that one would get:

2 of b,d

1 of c,a

1 of a,d

The outer array foreach to get get to the inner array to be done first. Not sure what is the approach in counting unique array values. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function count_pairs($array) {
    foreach ($array as &$pair) {
        $pair = implode(', ', $pair);
    }
    return array_count_values($array);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you would use "&$pair" and not just "$pair"?

Comment: Without `&`, `$array` won't be changed.

Comment: FatMachine's comment indicates why every answer should include an educational explanation.